# Code formatting is not working

Tags: bug, code-formatting

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27561561/1868660) when I am trying to format the code (the first code block after 'Default Params', in which }); is not formatted) is not working as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you have a code block immediately following a list item, you have to indent the code four more spaces.

Comment: :( still facing issue in edit.

Comment: @SubodhGhulaxe Because it's not indented enough spaces.

Comment: @SubodhGhulaxe Check it out now. I just added another space.