# Why does code formatting not work in this question?

Tags: support, code-formatting, markdown-rendering

I found the following suggested edit in the review queue:

[suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14998746), [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41834060/how-can-i-set-by-default-first-position-selected-in-android-listview)

The multi-line code was previously formatted using `` `…` `` and it is suggested to be replaced with `<code>…</code>`. I tried to remove the HTML tags. Since the code block is already indented, I expected it to format as a block code automatically. However, it keeps to render as a plain text. Why does this happen?

[image: formatting issue screenshot]

Including 4 more spaces like in [Code formatting is not working](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313587/code-formatting-is-not-working) does not help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The code was pasted with [U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR](https://codepoints.net/U+2028) characters:

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {\u2028
    final ViewHolder holder;\u2028\u2028\u2028
        if (view == null) {\u2028\u2028holder = new ViewHolder();\u2028
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_homelistrow, null);\u2028
            holder.list_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_text);\u2028
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check_change);\u2028\u2028
            holder.button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.change_button);\u2028
            holder.flag = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_image);\u2028
            //holder.Text_header=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_text);\u2028
            view.setTag(holder);\u2028\u2028} else {\u2028
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();\u2028
        }\u2028
    }
```

When you remove those the block is rendered correctly.

Comment: @Melebius: I've re-edited based of the source of the first revision, replacing each U+2028 character with a `\n` newline.

Comment: Is it possible to show these "non-normal" characters in the editor? Or do we have to copy the contents elsewhere to find out?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: the editor is not equipped to alter the display of every single weird Unicode character. I did figure out what was going on by bisection (removing half of the text until the problem went away), but I did then have to use the source text and Python to turn non-ASCII characters into escape sequences to arrive at the final conclusion.

Comment: Feature Request: Show "weird" Unicode characters as escape sequences... only semi-serious