# Can posts to Stack Overflow be fingerprinted using hidden Unicode characters?

Tags: discussion

Let's see if this works:

```swift
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

let str = "‌​​‌​​​⁠‌‌​​‌​‌⁠‌‌​‌‌​​⁠‌‌​‌‌​​⁠‌‌​‌‌‌‌⁠‌​‌‌​​⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌‌​‌​​​⁠‌‌​‌​​‌⁠‌‌​​‌​​⁠‌‌​​‌​​⁠‌‌​​‌​‌⁠‌‌​‌‌‌​⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌‌‌​​​​⁠‌‌​​​​‌⁠‌‌‌‌​​‌⁠‌‌​‌‌​​⁠‌‌​‌‌‌‌⁠‌‌​​​​‌⁠‌‌​​‌​​Hello, playground"
```

Copy the "Hello, playground" above and decrypt it using [Spacecrypt](https://pug.sh/spacecrypt/).

Do hidden payloads like this pose a problem for Stack Overflow code fragments?

It appears that these hidden payloads can work their way into code, not just data (such as the string shown above.) For example, this code contains variables which contain the Unicode encoding sequence:

```swift
let ‌​‌​‌‌‌⁠‌‌​‌​​​⁠‌‌​​​​‌⁠‌‌‌​‌​​⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌‌​​‌​​⁠‌‌​‌‌‌‌⁠‌‌​​‌​‌⁠‌‌‌​​‌‌⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌‌​​‌‌​⁠‌‌​‌‌‌‌⁠‌‌​‌‌‌‌⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌‌​​‌​‌⁠‌‌‌​‌‌​⁠‌‌​​‌​‌⁠‌‌​‌‌‌​⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌‌​‌‌​‌⁠‌‌​​‌​‌⁠‌‌​​​​‌⁠‌‌​‌‌‌​⁠‌‌‌‌‌‌foo = 111111111
print("foo = \(‌​‌​‌‌‌⁠‌‌​‌​​​⁠‌‌​​​​‌⁠‌‌‌​‌​​⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌‌​​‌​​⁠‌‌​‌‌‌‌⁠‌‌​​‌​‌⁠‌‌‌​​‌‌⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌‌​​‌‌​⁠‌‌​‌‌‌‌⁠‌‌​‌‌‌‌⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌‌​​‌​‌⁠‌‌‌​‌‌​⁠‌‌​​‌​‌⁠‌‌​‌‌‌​⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌‌​‌‌​‌⁠‌‌​​‌​‌⁠‌‌​​​​‌⁠‌‌​‌‌‌​⁠‌‌‌‌‌‌foo)")
let ‌​​​‌‌​⁠‌​‌​‌​‌⁠‌​​​​‌​⁠‌​​​​​‌⁠‌​‌​​‌​⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌​‌​‌‌‌⁠‌​​‌​​​⁠‌​​‌​​‌⁠‌​​​​‌‌⁠‌​​‌​​​⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌​​‌​​‌⁠‌​‌​​‌‌⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌​‌​​​​⁠‌​‌​​‌​⁠‌​​​‌​‌⁠‌​‌​‌​​⁠‌​‌​‌​​⁠‌​‌‌​​‌⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌​​​​‌‌⁠‌​​‌‌​​⁠‌​​‌‌‌‌⁠‌​‌​​‌‌⁠‌​​​‌​‌⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌​‌​‌​​⁠‌​​‌‌‌‌⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌​​​‌‌​⁠‌​‌​‌​‌⁠‌​‌​​‌​⁠‌​​​​‌​⁠‌​​‌‌‌‌bar = 111111111
print("bar = \(‌​​​‌‌​⁠‌​‌​‌​‌⁠‌​​​​‌​⁠‌​​​​​‌⁠‌​‌​​‌​⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌​‌​‌‌‌⁠‌​​‌​​​⁠‌​​‌​​‌⁠‌​​​​‌‌⁠‌​​‌​​​⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌​​‌​​‌⁠‌​‌​​‌‌⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌​‌​​​​⁠‌​‌​​‌​⁠‌​​​‌​‌⁠‌​‌​‌​​⁠‌​‌​‌​​⁠‌​‌‌​​‌⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌​​​​‌‌⁠‌​​‌‌​​⁠‌​​‌‌‌‌⁠‌​‌​​‌‌⁠‌​​​‌​‌⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌​‌​‌​​⁠‌​​‌‌‌‌⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌​​​‌‌​⁠‌​‌​‌​‌⁠‌​‌​​‌​⁠‌​​​​‌​⁠‌​​‌‌‌‌bar)")
let bar = 1

‌​‌​‌‌‌⁠‌‌​‌​​​⁠‌‌​​​​‌⁠‌‌‌​‌​​⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌‌​​‌​​⁠‌‌​‌‌‌‌⁠‌‌​​‌​‌⁠‌‌‌​​‌‌⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌‌​​‌‌​⁠‌‌​‌‌‌‌⁠‌‌​‌‌‌‌⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌‌​​‌​‌⁠‌‌‌​‌‌​⁠‌‌​​‌​‌⁠‌‌​‌‌‌​⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌‌​‌‌​‌⁠‌‌​​‌​‌⁠‌‌​​​​‌⁠‌‌​‌‌‌​⁠‌‌‌‌‌‌foo * ‌​​​‌‌​⁠‌​‌​‌​‌⁠‌​​​​‌​⁠‌​​​​​‌⁠‌​‌​​‌​⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌​‌​‌‌‌⁠‌​​‌​​​⁠‌​​‌​​‌⁠‌​​​​‌‌⁠‌​​‌​​​⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌​​‌​​‌⁠‌​‌​​‌‌⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌​‌​​​​⁠‌​‌​​‌​⁠‌​​​‌​‌⁠‌​‌​‌​​⁠‌​‌​‌​​⁠‌​‌‌​​‌⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌​​​​‌‌⁠‌​​‌‌​​⁠‌​​‌‌‌‌⁠‌​‌​​‌‌⁠‌​​​‌​‌⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌​‌​‌​​⁠‌​​‌‌‌‌⁠‌​​​​​⁠‌​​​‌‌​⁠‌​‌​‌​‌⁠‌​‌​​‌​⁠‌​​​​‌​⁠‌​​‌‌‌‌bar
```

Both `foo` and `bar` are not what they appear to be. The second `let bar` definition is the give away: the Swift compiler should generate an error, yet this code is completely valid.

I think this poses some serious issues, not just for Stack Overflow, but for the languages which are discussed on this Q&A site. Hidden characters in code make effective code review *much* more difficult. In the example above, a quick review of the code would lead someone to believe that `foo * bar` would be `11111111`, not the actual value of `12345678987654321`. This would be an easy way for someone to hide a security vulnerability [in plain sight](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/).

It's also very difficult to see these hidden characters at the point-of-origin: They don't appear at all in Safari's Web Inspector and in Chrome the HTML entities blend right in with the other HTML and CSS for this site. You also have to ask yourself when you last examined the code on this site at this level of detail. We all see stuff that looks useful and copy & paste with abandon.

Should Stack Overflow takes steps to mitigate this situation?

For code, I think it's pretty clear that there should be some kind of filter that strips out this hidden information. Visitors to this site aren't expecting identifiers that use tricks, and if stripping them out breaks the sample code, so be it.

For data, it's a much harder answer: the zero width joiners are a part of the Unicode specification because they have a useful purpose. Maybe my "Hello, playground" string was doing something productive and not encoding a fingerprint. Maybe some kind of visual indicator is needed to let the visitor know that there was more to the data than meets the eye.

Comment: Yes, it looks like they can.

Comment: Heh, this is neat

Comment: I added the little bit at the end to convert this into a discussion, because I think this is interesting to talk about. If that wasn't the intent, feel free to rework the question part.

Comment: Why would anyone want to?

Comment: @MartinSmith Because copy-and-paste into production code happens, a lot. It's actually an interesting question, can somebody be tricked into introducing bugs or vulnerabilities into their apps by copying and pasting from SO?

Comment: Somebody ought to explain how to make this exploitable.  And how to do this and still stay anonymous.  Without that it is but a curiosity that has already been covered broadly in Q+A.  Invariably accidentally :)

Comment: AFAIK this isn't particularly dangerous for SO, it's meant to find out who leaked government secrets to the press, for example. See http://www.reddit.com/r/netsec/comments/7nakb5/fingerprinting_text_with_zerowidth_characters/ for an article with some additional info.

Comment: @HansPassant *"how to do this and still stay anonymous"* - well, *that* half of your request is easy enough to solve: post anonymously. (Or pseudonymously. I know I *seem* to be a white male called Mark Amery from London, but really I'm a Chinese hacker named Jing.)

Comment: It's the reverse of [SO removes some unicode characters...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342546) – according to an answer (not mine, the other), SO is already doing *some* sanitizing of Markdown. Zero-width characters ought to be safe to remove, but how about fixed spaces? They have been cause of *code pr0blems* in the past as careful examination of copied code revealed, so they are useful to a certain limited extend. [Contra my own point: At the far end, there are always bound to be pr0blems that *cannot* be posted due to local formatting.]

Comment: Is the "danger" that somebody could copy and paste code into their software that _looks_ like it works, but in the end it won't run because of the hidden characters? Or is there danger of injecting malicious code as well? I did a really basic test script, and if I try to run a basic line of code that has been "fingerprinted", the interpreter reads the hidden characters and throws an undefined method error.

Comment: The real problem is that your OS-level code editor doesn't show you invisible Unicode characters, or that you've set that editor such that those characters are not displayed. Any half-decent native-OS based editor for code (into which the snippet is being pasted) should have the ability to show "non-printing" characters. This is a basic function, without which you should disqualify the editor for editing code. Turning that feature on should be your default config. That doesn't mean that SO shouldn't show these, just that they should be blindingly obvious when pasted into your project.

Comment: This should also be opt-in per SE if possible. I'm not sure, but I expect CodeGolf will find ways to make this fun.

Comment: If you remove all support for zero-width characters from SO then question about dealing with zero-width characters will be problematic.

Comment: The point is well taken but there have been a number of times when I have been able to find an answer based on an examination of (accidentally) spoofed text being accurately copy-and-pasted into a question. So there are arguments both ways.

Comment: I have actually seen questions come up where the problem was a unicode equivalent character. See, things like this might actually come up in the wild, so it may cause _even more_ confusion if the editor strips them out.

Comment: This has nothing to do with spacecrypt and hiding specific information in that manner. It’s just to do with invivisble characters. Unless the person copying and pasting pasted it into spacecrypt first for some weird reason

Comment: @Jonathan.: Who said it had anything to do with Spacecrypt? Spacecrypt is just one tool, used solely to illustrate the example. Hiding specific information in this manner, however, is the whole *premise* of this question. Someone could exploit the use of invisible characters for either something benign like fingerprinting, or possibly other, nefarious purposes.

Comment: @meagar: "can somebody be tricked into introducing bugs or vulnerabilities into their apps by copying and pasting from SO?" I'm not sure why you think this would need to involve invisible Unicode characters at all. Surely many people will be more than happy to copy and paste any old code that claims to solve their problem, especially if it actually does so (aside from also doing other things). Admittedly, without invisible characters there is at least a much better chance another user will spot the problems and highlight them before the ill-advised copying happens.

Comment: @JeroenMostert that all goes without saying, which is why I didn’t say it.

Comment: @meagar: then I'm not sure why you consider your question interesting, since you already seem to agree the answer is "yes".

Comment: Related: [Consider displaying zero-width space characters in code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351807/consider-displaying-zero-width-space-characters-in-code-blocks)

Comment: I just thought of a neat trick: embed invisibles in *strings* in any code you write for Stack Overflow. Then you may be able to see where it pops up in the wild. (Dibs on "one ZWJ before the first lowercase" – that'll be my personal sig!)

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert: When someone copies code that has very glaring bugs or security issues (especially code in answers that *outright state these upfront*), that's their own fault. When someone unwittingly copies code that has issues introduced by things only the keenest of eyes or most paranoid of security audits would notice, it's a little harder to pin all the blame on them for just copying the code. Like it or not, **people will copy code**, and the way to train them not to copy code **is not by deliberately introducing malicious code into your posts**.

Comment: @iBug: You sure that isn't just browsers stripping out the `javascript:` portion automatically? That's a security measure put in by browsers themselves to mitigate social engineering attacks much more prevalent outside of SO.

Comment: @BoltClock [Sure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment985615_3122).

Comment: @iBug: OK. Might have been better to just link to that instead of providing an example that doesn't actually demonstrate what you said.

Comment: FYI, Stack Overflow actively inserts invisible characters to certain code blocks in comments. For example `document.body.removeChild(document.body.appendChild(document‌​.createElement('styl‌​e')));` it won't execute at all if you copy it directly to your browser's address bar, but it works if you type it by hand.

Comment: @BoltClock Wrong example removed.

Comment: Even if you type it again and post the working code as a comment, there'll be invisible characters inserted after you submit your comment.

Answer (score 70):

One *quite simple* solution I can think of would be to add a "*show invisibles*" checkbox on code and pre blocks.

With simple CSS and a custom font* handling these invisible characters, it should be possible to display these conditionally.

For instance, here is the output of such a feature available in my text editor:

[image]

<sub>*I unfortunately don't know such a font yet, but it shouldn't be too hard to make one.</sub>

Comment: Yes, having an optional way to show invisible is a nice way. An alternative that I use on Wikipedia for the same purpose is to support user CSS customization, as one can do on [monobook.css](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:MyPage/monobook.css) ([French doc on user CSS](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aide:Personnaliser_l%27interface)). That way, users, that feel like it, can tweak their font and more by themselves, without the need for 6-8 weeks of development from the StackOverflow team. Disclosure: I'm a Wikipedia Admin.

Comment: @Cœur the same can be achieved with userscripts, and that requires no maintenance or upkeep from Stack Overflow.

Comment: Such a "show invisible" should first detect invisibles.  Maybe "show raw unicode" should show up whenever any code points outside of ASCII are used, to fix the "alternative a" trick.

Comment: Common implementation for hidden, out-of-ASCII characters: highlight character with red, if invisible render as space

Comment: Please note regarding my previous comment that it would be a potentially insufficient change to mitigate the homograph attacks like in @chockenberry's example of `fo\u{00F3}` vs `foo\u{0301}`. Maybe an equivalent of [monobook.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:MyPage/monobook.js) would actually be required.

Comment: Notepad++ has an option to do this. :) It's really nice.

Answer (score 55):

This is a very deep problem in Unicode, and stripping zero-width characters doesn't get you very far in fixing it. The above Swift homograph-attack is easily generated without any zero-widths:

```swift
let foo = 111111111
print("foo = \(foo)")
let bar = 111111111
print("bar = \(bar)")
let bаr = 1   // How is that legal? LATIN SMALL LETTER A != CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER А

foo * bаr  // 12345678987654321
```

There are many homographs in Unicode, and even more near-homographs. Using homographs is an easier and less detectable version of this attack, since they don't create the quirky IDE behaviors zero-widths do. If this were a fruitful attack, we should see it in homograph attacks. This isn't to say it's impossible to exploit or useless to mitigate, but when attackers fail to widely use a class of attack that has been known for years, there's a reason. Homograph exploitation of domain names is a major problem, so it isn't a case that attackers are unaware of the possibilities.

Are there any known cases of successful homograph attacks on Stack Overflow, coding forums, or other coding sites? "No one has been caught doing it" isn't sufficient reason by itself not to employ a mitigation, but if someone *has* successfully pulled this off, then that definitely changes things.

Reducing Stack Overflow questions to Latin-1 would make a wide variety of Unicode questions impossible to ask. (Not to mention the impact on askers who use non-Latin identifiers and comments in their code. I often encounter non-English sample code, and that's fine IMO.) I believe that's a non-starter.

Stripping zero-width characters in the Markdown may be acceptable, since they can make the question harder to understand, and it is often better to express questions about them with visible names (like "ZWJ"). But I've answered questions where the problem turned out to be weird stuff in the string that I had to paste into [xxd](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd) to figure out. In any case, this isn't much of a security mitigation because homographs are so much easier.

A banner indicating that the post includes non-Latin-1 characters, and a mechanism for highlighting all of them (and exposing any that are zero-width) would provide some security benefit IMO, but it feels awkward, and somewhat hostile to non-native-English speakers. I don't recommend it, but at least it could be effective.

Comment: The Swift compiler doesn't even take canonical equivalence of identifiers into account (even though its String class does.) For example: let foó = 1 // fo\u{00F3}; let foó = 2 // foo\u{0301}; foó == foó // false; As you say, this homophone problem goes deep.

Comment: As I commented earlier elsethread, on your "turned out to be weird stuff in the string": this is only possible because the Markdown editor did not already strip out the pr0blem. If it had done, there would be no other option than "can't reproduce, try this: *long list of suggestions*". More sanitizing would possibly lead to more such answers ("more" > 0), less sanitizing to a greater chance of misinforming/intentionally damaging/trolling. .. I don't know what's less bad.

Comment: wow: a technical answer on-topic on meta.

Comment: My lame claim to fame is having a 100+ scoring answer to a question related to Unicode homographs (even if it's not a security question per se): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674577/how-to-compare-unicode-characters-that-look-alike

Comment: @chockenberry: the same applies to other languages supporting unicode source, e.g. Java. These aren’t even homoglyphs, it’s the same character, but encoded differently, and the language considers them different identifiers. It might be even the case that the IDE’s editor, being an extension of a generic text editor, respects canonical equivalence and doesn’t show that these identifiers are different. It might even be the case that the original form gets lost when doing copy&paste, so some SO users might not be able to reproduce your problem, telling you that the problem must be on your side.

Comment: A banner indicating non-Latin-1 characters and automatic highlighting would seem to improve readability, even when security wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I VOTE WE REVERT TO EBCDIC.

Answer (score 6):

> Should Stack Overflow takes steps to mitigate this situation?
>
> For code, I think it's pretty clear that there should be some kind of filter that strips out this hidden information. Visitors to this site aren't expecting identifiers that use tricks, and if stripping them out breaks the sample code, so be it.

Not until if and when it's demonstrated there's an actual problem. At least, not mitigated in the way you suggest.

And I would be very wary of doing so in any case. As [already pointed out in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361390/can-posts-to-stack-overflow-be-fingerprinted-using-hidden-unicode-characters?cb=1#comment544758_361390), there are also scenarios where hidden or otherwise unexpected characters in the code *are the problem*. Stripping them out would block any effort to answer the question, and adding insult to injury would likely result in the question getting closed as "off-topic", lacking a code example that reproduces the problem.

I'm sympathetic to the apparent security vulnerability. But so far, I've seen no evidence it's a genuine problem. Fact is, from a hacker's point of view, there are far more profitable targets, available with less effort.

How many posts would a hacker have to answer, taking the time to understand the problem well enough to provide a *genuine* solution but which also includes some hidden code that can actually penetrate some secure environment, before they sucker just the right person into pasting code that can steal important information or gain access to important systems? It's hard to imagine this ever being an actual thing.

And doing it with data? Even trickier.

In the unlikely event it does begin to look like there's a problem, the most I'd suggest is adding something to the web page to alert the reader to the presence of undisplayed information. Maybe a little banner displayed underneath a code block, for example, with a way to show text that otherwise would have been hidden.

Comment: I couldn't disagree more - there's a clear and present issue of users getting different information than they were presented. Saying that any potential security issue has no practical application has been proven time and again to be just begging for someone to publish a practical attack. I would consider a visual indicator of _some_ kind - your suggestion of a banner under a code block is very likable IMO - to be a valuable and even necessary mitigation.

Comment: "scenarios where hidden or otherwise unexpected characters in the code are the problem" - maybe make it clear to the poster with some kind of indicator (before they post the question) that there are hidden characters in their code.

Comment: Attack vectors should be closed or mitigated *before* they are exploited, not after.

Answer (score -10):

The answer to your question, can it happen today, is YES.

Here is how the source would look to a search engine... I might not be able to find this post if I was using a quoted expression `"str = Hello"` to search on that particular code fragment. This would pose a problem for me if I was desperate to get this particular question answered.  Searchability is my number one requirement for Stack Overflow and related sites.

[image]

Comment: If this were embedded in a code block...I somehow doubt that it'd interfere with search engine crawlers.  Besides, they're pretty sophisticated nowadays anyway.

Comment: @Makoto So many saying that this should be allowed, even if there is a clean way to prevent it without impacting unicode users? That's interesting.  Why?

Comment: I'm simply finding faults with your argument against.  If your angle is that the search functionality would be impacted, you *might* be right...but I disagree that this is the only standing issue to fix with it.

Comment: @Makoto okay thanks! I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Makoto hey I just tested on google.... if I search on `'Hello Playground'` this post comes up #4 in the search results... if search on `'str = Hello Playground'` or `'str = "Hello Playground"'`, it is not in the result.  I'm just saying... if the most important feature for everyone is search ... and it can be broken....  that should be reason enough to fix it, provided the fix doesn't hurt legit unicode use etc.

Comment: Well, I mean ultimately I can't see this actually causing a problem. It's not often that I find myself searching for exact code on google and expecting a result on Stack Overflow. I actually don't think I have ever felt the urge to do that.

Comment: Searchability is number one concern? Even the SO team says they have no intention to fix the search engine so that it at least finds correct results. The search engine of SO is completely broken, regardless of these unicode characters

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Going back to Joel and Jeff's podcasts... SO was built around Google.  Create accurate, timely and useable content optimized for Google to crawl, which blew away all the PHP-based forum sites that were all we had in those days. I guess it's okay if there are users now who don't agree with the core strategy or don't want/need to search SO for source.

Comment: I'd agree with the idea if there was a basic search engine here. It's extremely frustrating to having to go to google to search for duplicates because the built-in engine doesn't find them (easiest case: search `c# null reference exception` instead of `c# nullreferenceexception`)